# Transition fade on images not working

Tags: html, css, image, transition

I would like a section of images on my portfolio to be 'faint' and then when a mouse hovers over for them be at 100% opacity.

I thought I had the css working properly but I'm not stuck as it only seems to show the images as faint but when hovering nothing happens.

Many thanks for you help in advance.

MY HTML:

```
<div class="portfolioimages"><div class="images-responsive">
        <img src="images/portfolio/brand/platinum-logo.jpg" /><img src="images/portfolio/brand/platinum-stationery.jpg" />
        <img src="images/portfolio/brand/speed-trades-stationery.jpg" /><img src="images/portfolio/brand/speed-trades-logo.jpg" />
        <img src="images/portfolio/brand/crumbs-cupcakes-logo.jpg" /><img src="images/portfolio/brand/crumbs-cupcakes-stationery.jpg" />
        <img src="images/portfolio/brand/adam-and-gaskell-stationery.jpg" /><img src="images/portfolio/brand/adam-and-gaskell-logo.jpg" />
        <img src="images/portfolio/brand/es-logo.jpg" /><img src="images/portfolio/brand/es-stationery.jpg" />
        </div></div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.images-responsive {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
    -moz-transition:0.5s;
    -o-transition:0.5s;
}

.images-responsive: hover {
    opacity:1;
    transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
    -moz-transition:0.5s;
    -o-transition:0.5s;
}
```

Comment: also add 
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't applying the CSS to the images, just the div. needs to be

```
.images-responsive img {
cursor:pointer;
opacity:0.7;
transition:0.5s;
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
-moz-transition:0.5s;
-o-transition:0.5s;
```

}

```
.images-responsive img: hover {
opacity:1;
transition:0.5s;
-webkit-transition:0.5s;
-moz-transition:0.5s;
-o-transition:0.5s;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space in front of `hover` here:

```
.images-responsive: hover {
```

You need this, with no spaces:

```
.images-responsive:hover {
```

[Here's a kitten to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/99jcq/).